# "Она работает в кассе" или "на кассе"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

-

Answer (score 1):

Это смотря, что за касса такая. Если касса - помещение, то да, в кассе. Но это, имхо, в современных реалиях случай не самый типичный. Кассир - он и так в кассе, вряд ли про него так скажут. Разве про уборщицу или там ремонт делают.
Если же касса - аппарат в магазине, за которым работает кассир (кассир-продавец и т.д.), то на кассе.
И наконец, если касса - участок бухучета, то там бухгалтер-кассир работает тоже НА. Хотя ещё чаще отвечает ЗА или прото на нем сидит.

Comment: Согласна со вторым ответом. Вряд ли про кассира в супермаркете можно сказать, что она "в кассе" .

Answer (score 0):

Касса - это помещение. Следовательно, *работает **в** кассе*. Даже если это рабочее место в магазине в большом зале, все равно это место, **кабинка**, где стоит этот аппарат и находится обслуживающий его работник. В словарях не нашла каких-то норм, разъясняющих данный случай. Лично мне 'на кассе' режет слух. Может, у кого-то другое мнение?

Answer (score 0):

На кассе--правильный ответ,ибо быть внутри кассы нельзя.Так же:на радио.на ТВ и др.

Answer (score 0):

По мне так: касса работает в магазине, можно быть либо за кассой, работая за ней, как за партой, либо у кассы, то есть приобретая товар, стоя у кассы. На кассе может сидеть лишь попугай)))